# XHProf not displaying runs but empty table

Tags: debugging

I'm trying to profile a drupal website using xhprof. I manage to install it and configure drupal to use it (using the devel module) but I have a problem to visualize the result.

First, for some reason I didn't manage to get the access rights to xhprof_html through apache. Instead of using apache I just cd into xhprof_html directory and run php -S myhost:8080. I can then see the main page with all the runs, but when I select a run, it's empty. I can see the table and everything but there is no functions displayed. When I look at the run with a text editor it seems ok.

What am I doing wrong ? Is there another tool to visualize xhprof runs ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the developper module (used to activate XHProf) use the site name to generate the run. The site name contains the `&` character which messes up the URL corresponding to run.